# kpfonts makes fleqn and leqno options ignored when passed via \PassOptionsToClass

Tags: amsmath, class-options, kpfonts

The following M(n)WE points out that `fleqn` (and `leqno` as well) option, passed to the class thanks to `\PassOptionsToClass`, is taken in account except if `kpfonts` package is loaded (no problem if the option is passed thanks to `\@classoptionslist` or as `\documentclass` option):

```
% \makeatletter
% \def\@classoptionslist{fleqn}
% \makeatother
\PassOptionsToClass{fleqn}{article}%
\documentclass%[fleqn]
{article}
% \usepackage{kpfonts}
%
\begin{document}
Foo
\[
  F
\]
\end{document}
```

Interestingly, if `kpfonts` is loaded with `noamsmath` option, no trouble (but then `kpfonts`'s `\widering` command cannot be used).

Do you see what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kpfonts` not really involved other than it loads `amsmath`, you see the same if you load `amsmath` directly.

`amsmath` redefines the left alignment so you need to pass the option to the package:

```
% \makeatletter
% \def\@classoptionslist{fleqn}
% \makeatother
%\PassOptionsToClass{fleqn}{article}%
\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}%
\documentclass%[fleqn]
{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\begin{document}
Foo
\[
  F
\]
\end{document}
```

If you pass an option to the class it is *just* an option to the class, unlike an option in the explicit `[..]` list it is not a global option seen by all packages, so you need to pass `fleqn` to `amsmath` not to `article`.